# Add to Cart Forms Buttons disables Boost Module Caching

Tags: 7, commerce, performance, caching

I've installed boost on my drupal 7 site with commerce setup. Boost is working fine, but any pages with a form, such as an add to cart form. It will disable boost caching. I need a way to ajax load these form buttons after the page is loaded so boost doesnt cache the forms.

What methods are there to solve this solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the solution by using the following module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_link

One issue I had to was getting these links to display in a Views output as this module turns the add to cart input fields into url links. There was no option in views to change this:

I did a work around to get this to work. Apparently you can just append the product id to the form of this link:

/cart/add/nojs/[product-id]/random-token-variable

I'm not sure what the token is for, but you can just put anything in there and it will still add it to the cart. It works for anonymous, but when your logged in, the link will hit you to an access denied page. I had to do the following to get it to work for authenticated users by commenting out 3 lines in commercie_cart_link.module:

[image]
I'm not sure what the token is for.